# Move files to newly created folders more efficiently

Tags: python

I want to group  a list of files into sub-folders based on some substring in their name

The files are of the form

- pie_riverside_10.png
- stack_oak_20.png
- scatter_mountain_10.png

and I want to use the starting substring (e.g. pie, stack, scatter) and the integer substring (e.g. 10,20) as the sub-directory name for grouping the files..

The code below is only example- if I actually do that approach I have to create at least 75-80 folders  manually with `elif` statements, which is inefficient.

I am just curious if there is a better way to do this?

EDIT: The current code assumes there is already a folder created, but in real scenario I do not have the folders created and I do not want to have to create 70-80 subfolders- I am trying to make script to create those folders for me.

```
import shutil
import os

source = 'C:/Users/Xx/Documents/plots/'

pie_charts_10= 'C:/Users/Xx/Documents/pie_charts_10/'
pie_charts_20= 'C:/Users/Xx/Documents/pie_charts_20/'
stack_charts_10 = 'C:/Users/Xx/Documents/stack_charts_10 /'
scatter_charts_10 = 'C:/Users/Xx/Documents/scatter_charts_10 /'

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if (f.startswith("pie") and f.endswith("10.png")):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), pie_charts_10)
    elif (f.startswith("pie") and f.endswith("20.png")):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), pie_charts_20 )
    elif (f.startswith("stack") and f.endswith("10.png")):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), stack_charts_10 )
    elif (f.startswith("scatter ") and f.endswith("10.png")):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), scatter_charts_10 )
    else:
        print("No file")
```

Comment: Can you fix your code, as you've left several things undefined: `pie_charts`, `stack_charts`, etc. Also, is there any reason why you only want certain suffixes(16, 14, 12, etc)?

Comment: so `pie18.png` must not be moved in `pie_charts` ? illogical.

Comment: @TemporalWolf i just realize that mistake, sorry I try to not make example from script. (16, 14, 12) is arbitrary way I wrote, but start and ends of the file name should match order to move to folder

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre correct, because I might have another folder where I would only have files contains starting with `pie` and ending with `18.png`

Comment: you want to put files into folders based on what they star with ? maybe explain a bit more what you are trying to do in words rather than hope someone infers from the code

Comment: This is would be a simpler problem using bash, rather than Python. Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with bash development.

Comment: @dermen sorry for the confusion I will edit my question

Comment: pie_charts_10 and pie_charts_20 are the same path? Anyway seems you have a solution accepted, but it is just hard to even understand the question

Comment: @dermen no, its not, I added more information to make it clear. Excuse my lack of english :/

Comment: ok - so now is  the folder pie_charts_10 supposed to contain all the pie graph files  from pie_graph_1.png to pie_graph_10.png , and the folder pie_charts_20 contain all the files from pie_graph_11.png up to pie_graph_20.png ? Something like that ?

Comment: btw you can create a folder with [os.path.makedirs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs)

Comment: folder pie_charts_10, suppose to contains all the files startswith pie and endswith 10. Example files, pie_springfield_10.png, pie_oakwood_10.png, I know numbers made things confusing . Also if there is file pie_riverside_11.png, script need to create new folder for this add this file to that folder

Comment: ok - that is critical info for the post..

Comment: The answer was provided is not correct for my case, but accepted anyway because it was my fault not making clear what I was asking.

Comment: Correct, every file `prefix_bas_suffix.png` into folder  `prefix_charts_suffix/` there is no files with just `prefix_suffix.png` all has something in the middle

Comment: In the future, please provide a [mcve]... as your specifications changed. Glad you got an answer though :)

Comment: I really appreciated for the help. Its all my fault, I was trying to quick to create the question. After everyone asking question all type question, I realized my mistake :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
# assume you have files in a folder
source = './files' # some directory
files = os.listdir(source)
print files
#['pie_river_1.png', 'pie_mountain_11.png', 'scatter_grass_12.png', 'stack_field_30.png']
```

Now you want to group them into subfolders based on what they start with and what number they have before the extension

```
subdir_root = './subfolders'

for f in files:
    fig_type = f.split('_')[0]
    fig_num = f.split('.png')[0].split('_')[-1]
    subdir_name = '%s_charts_%s'%(fig_type, fig_num) # name of dir, e.g. pie_charts_10
    subdir = os.path.join( subdir_root, subdir_name ) # path to dir
    if not os.path.exists(subdir): # if the dir does not exist , create it
        os.makedirs(subdir)

    f_src = os.path.join( source, f) # full path to source file
    f_dest = os.path.join( subdir, f) # full path to new destination file
    shutil.copy( f_src, f_dest ) # I changed to copy so you dont screw up your original files
```

on my compurer

```
$ ls ./files:
pie_mountain_11.png  pie_river_1.png      scatter_grass_12.png stack_field_30.png

$ ls -R ./subfolders
pie_charts_1      pie_charts_11     scatter_charts_12 stack_charts_30

subfolders//pie_charts_1:
pie_river_1.png

subfolders//pie_charts_11:
pie_mountain_11.png

subfolders//scatter_charts_12:
scatter_grass_12.png

subfolders//stack_charts_30:
stack_field_30.png
```

Obviously, you might have to change the code if edge cases arise.. but this should give you a good start...

Comment: I am trying to test the script now

Comment: this assumes each filename has the general form "%s_%s_%d.png"

Comment: I made same files name for myself, not getting any error, but nothing is been created too http://paste.ubuntu.com/24402751/

Comment: make sure your subfolder path is correct, put it in explicitly e.g. ```subdir_root = 'C:/Users/kilicm/Desktop/subfolders/```, and then also ensure that the subdir_root exists, for instance ```if not os.path.exists(subdir_root): os.makedirs(subdir_root)

Comment: It's working now!! Thank you so much for taking time and following thru to solve this issue. I can't thank enough!

Comment: now worries, it give me an excuse to work on something else while I am at work ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141912/discussion-between-mtkilic-and-dermen).

Comment: `f.split('.png')[0].split('_')[-1]` seems line a roundabout way of doing it. I'd recommend `f.split('_')[-1][:-4]` (which strips the last four characters off the filename.). It's worth noting, however, that both do not handle edge cases well: `bob.sh` for example.

Comment: :) I try to do same thing couple times but SO was to fast for me. Reddit has easier question and gives you more time to solve before someone else does :D

Comment: grabbing substrings will usually depend on specifics anyway.. in this case each file is a png...  could easily have split on the period in before the extension... e.g. 'bob.sh'.split('.')[0].split('_')[-1].. which would then yield 'bob'

Answer (score 3):

When you are looking to move files of the format `prefix_suffix.png` into folders `prefix_charts_suffix/`:

```
base = "C:/Users/Xx/Documents"
moved_types = ['png']

for f in files:
    pf = f.rsplit('.', 1)  # filename, prefix
    sf = pf[0].split("_")  # prefix, whatever, suffix
    if len(sf) >= len(pf) > 1 and pf[1] in moved_types:
        new_dir = "%s_charts_%s" % (sf[0], sf[-1])
        if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(base, new_dir):
            os.mkdirs(os.path.join(base, new_dir)
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), os.path.join(base, new_dir, f)
```

Which will work for the general case, grabbing and moving only files which end in `moved_types` and contain a `_` (which allows for splitting of a `prefix` and `suffix`).

See the relevant logic on [repl.it](https://repl.it/HMoW/0):

```
>>>['prefix_garbage_suffix.png', 'bob.sh', 'bob.bill.png', "pie_23.png", "scatter_big_1.png"]
Move prefix_garbage_suffix.png to prefix_charts_suffix
Move pie_23.png to pie_charts_23
Move scatter_big_1.png to scatter_charts_1
```

---

**EDIT**: I've preserved the original answer in case others need a solution where not every file should be moved or you can't infer the folder name from the file names.

If you need I would do something like:

```
identity_tuples = \
[('pie', '16.png', 'C:/Users/Xx/Documents/pie_charts/'),
 ('stack', '14.png', 'C:/Users/Xx/Documents/stack_charts/'),
 ('scatter', '12.png', 'C:/Users/Xx/Documents/scatter_charts/')]

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
  for identity_tuple in identity_tuples:
    if f.startswith(identity_tuple[0]) and f.endswith(identity_tuple[1]):
      shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), identity_tuple[2])
      break
  else:
    print("No file")
```

Now you just have to add a new identity tuple: `(prefix, suffix, destination)` for each type. If the path is common for all the destinations, you can change it to:

```
identity_tuples = \
[('pie', '16.png', 'pie_charts/'),
 ('stack', '14.png', 'stack_charts/'),
 ('scatter', '12.png', 'scatter_charts/')]

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
  for identity_tuple in identity_tuples:
    if f.startswith(identity_tuple[0]) and f.endswith(identity_tuple[1]):
      shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), "C:/Users/Xx/Documents/" + identity_tuple[2])
      break
  else:
    print("No file")
```

Note: This is using a `for/else` loop, in which `else` is only called if you don't hit a `break`.

If you need to make the directories, add this in before the `shutil.move()`:

```
if not os.path.exists(identity_tuple[2]):
    os.mkdirs(identity_tuple[2])  # Or "C:/Users/Xx/Documents/" + ...
```

Comment: idenity_tuple: please fix the remaining typo in the end. Otherwise, good. I would have used fnmatch with `pie*16.png`, etc... same solution...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks for the catch. I've corrected it. And I've never used `fnmatch`, I'll have to take a look at it.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yeah, that's what I get for manually trying to correct `repl.it` which defaults to using 2 space indentation

Comment: I am getting following error `FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists`

Comment: Also, let's assume if I have multiple image start with `pie` and endswith `18` all of them will be included under same folder right? I try to test but I got error, I am looking for solution now.

Comment: Yes. And my code should be functionally equivalent to yours... so any issue you encounter I would expect to see in both. I would add a `try/except` which spits out what file it is on and what it's trying to do to it.

Comment: Actually, i realize why error occurs. This scripts assumes there is folder already for each `pie_charts`, `stack_charts` and `scatter_charts` i

Comment: are you sure that destination doesn't already contain the file (or a file with the same name)?

Comment: I will still accept your answer, but my goals is not to create 70-80 folder myself, instead I want my script to create folder and add appropriate files to that folder

Comment: @mtkilic I added a fix for creating the folders as needed.

Comment: @mtkilic I added a more robust solution to your second question, although for all normal input it should perform similarly to dermen's answer.

Comment: @TemporalWolf Thank you, I will try this asap